# Read Data in Chunks Spark

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark, emr

I have a dataset in S3 that consists of over 7000 gzipped files that expand to several terrabytes.  I am trying to read the data transform it and write it back to S3 using Spark on EMR.  The problem I keep running into is that the RDD is too big to fit in memory and as such the process of transforming the RDD slows down to a snails pace as the RDD has to be cached to disk ( it is needed again later to calculate stats ).  What I would like to do is to read 100 or a 1000 files process them and then start on the next 1000.  If there any way to do this built into the spark framework or do I need to manually list the files and chunk them.

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: You could try creating DataFrames, and save them as Parquet files. You can use `SaveMode.Append`, and only save the new rows. Then just open the `DataFrame` later when you want to calculate your stats.

Comment: One of the approach would be to use stream the files from your S3 directory using spark streaming and then process them one by one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994401/spark-streaming-on-a-s3-directory
One more ref.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402737/how-to-read-gz-files-in-spark-using-wholetextfiles